# multi attribute price multiplier

Tags: 6, ubercart, importing-exporting

I am working on building a site that has like 150 products each one is a different kind of moulding and has 7 wood types right now (more types may be added later and there are other products that wont use this) and needs to come in lengths up to 8 feet. What I want to be able to do and haven't haven't figured out the best way to is give 2 attributes one for the price of 1 foot of the moulding in that type and one to choose a number of feet (possibly another to choose how many of these pieces you want) right now each type of wood is being created separately and I am using custom sized products to calculate the length (site is still under development so I only have like 4 products that were manually created)

To sum it up what I'd like to do is create a product lets call it model 001 with attributes for wood type that change the price and then an attribute for length that multiplies the price from the wood type by the selected length and can be modified by an import/export module

anyone have any ideas on how to do this  without creating like 1,000 products?
currently using drupal 6 and have tried numerous other module combinations to get this working but would be willing to upgrade to 7 if necessary as the only module preventing me from doing so is custom sized products

Any help is much appreciated.